# Can MSBuild be explicitly instructed that a partial incremental rebuild is possible for a target?

Tags: msbuild

I'm a competent user of GNU *make* on Unix, tasked with writing a build system using MSBuild on Windows 7.  (Cygwin is not an option)

The MSBuild documentation on [partial incremental builds](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee264087.aspx) states that:

> MSBuild attempts to find a 1-to-1 mapping between the values of [*the Inputs and Outputs attributes*].
>
> [...]
>
> 1-to-1 mappings are typically produced by item transformations.

If 1-to-1 mappings are *typically* produced by item transformations, are there any *other* ways in which they may they be produced?

The page contains the following example target:

```
<Target Name="Backup" Inputs="@(Compile)" 
    Outputs="@(Compile->'$(BackupFolder)%(Identity).bak')">
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(Compile)" DestinationFiles=
        "@(Compile->'$(BackupFolder)%(Identity).bak')" />
</Target>
```

It bothers me that the transformation from the `@(Compile)` Item to the set of .bak files is duplicated.  It appears once in the Target's `Outputs` attribute, and once in the Copy Task's `DestinationFiles` attribute.

I'd like to be able to specify the transformation just once, preferably declaring an Item for the backup files.  I might want to use the same Item in other Tasks and Targets.  For example:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <BackupFiles Include="@(Compile->'$(BackupFolder)%(Identity).bak')" />
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="Backup" Inputs="@(Compile)" Outputs="@(BackupFiles)">
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(Compile)" DestinationFiles="@(BackupFiles)" />
</Target>
```

Then I could use `@(BackupFiles)` as the `Outputs` of the Target, the `DestinationFiles` of the `Copy`, and potentially elsewhere too. **However, if I do this then partial incremental building stops happening**.  If *all* outputs are up to date then the target is correctly skipped, but if *some* outputs are out of date then the target is run for *all* inputs.  It appears that the 1-to-1 mapping between `@(Compile)` and `@(BackupFiles)` is not identified when the target is run.

My questions are:

1. Can MSBuild be instructed that a 1-to-1 mapping exists between a Target's Inputs and Outputs attributes when it has failed to spot one itself, such as `@(Compile)` and `@(BackupFiles)` above?
2. Is there an equivalent to make's `$^`, `$<` and `$@` values.  That is; the inputs and outputs of the current target?  In particular I'd like to use something like `$@` as the `DestinationFiles` of the Copy task.  That is; *"Whatever you identified as the output; use that"*.

PS:  I have the "Using MSBuild and Team Foundation Build" book (2nd edition), if anybody wishes to refer to it.